# IOS: UItextfield disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, text-cursor

When we push on a textfield, a cursor appears in this textfield, but I don't want that this cursor appear. I want to make this textfield disabled, where you can't write inside.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can you set enabled property/userInteractionEnabled of text field to No in ViewDidLoad() using the code

```
textField.enabled = NO;
```

or

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with storyboards or .nib files and you want it to start out disabled you can also easily uncheck the enabled property in interface builder for some time-saving.