# How to Enable/Disable TextField SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I want to Enable/Disable a UITextField when i press a uibutton.

*When I Press The Enable uibutton it enables me to type on a uitextfield 
but when I press disable it disables me to type on my uitextfield.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS: UItextfield disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947965/ios-uitextfield-disabled)

Comment: Please share the what you have tried, and the community will step in to help.

Comment: Please checkout my answer and upvote it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply follow below steps to getting solution for your question :

1) Prepare IBOutlet for button and textfield

```
@IBOutlet var btnEnable : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnDisable : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var txtValue : UITextField!
```

2.) Now, in ViewDidLoad() put below lines for tagging button

```
self.btnEnable.tag = 0
self.btnDisable.tag = 1
```

3.) Now Create event and wired up this event with both button in storyboard. (note : same event wired up on both button Touch Up Inside)

```
@IBAction func btnTextfieldInteractionCalled(sender : UIButton)
{
    // "o" means called enable button and "1" means disable button
    if(sender.tag == 0)
    {
        self.txtValue.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    else if(sender.tag == 1)
    {
        self.txtValue.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

4.) Now run and check your result. Its work fine.. :)

Comment: How much you have now

Comment: Thank u so much...if need any help then contact me on pavangandhi10@gmail.com